# React Native 0.65 Navigation with stack screen and drawer very slow

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack, react-native-navigation, back

When you navigated to the previous screen the previous screen is locked.

It doesn't work for me on android. On ios it works perfectly. I am using rn 0.65 I do not understand why it does not work. Navigating forwards fine but backwards does not work.

"react-native": "0.65.1"
"@react-native-community/cli": "^6.0.0",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.0-alpha.3",
"react-native-screens": "^3.7.2",

Code

```
<NavigationContainer>
 <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        gestureEnabled: false,
      }}>
      {NoAuth.map(drawer =>
        drawer.name === 'login' ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            name={drawer.name}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
            key={drawer.name}
            component={LoginScreen}
          />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen
            name={drawer.name}
            options={{title: drawer.title}}
            key={drawer.name}
            component={
              drawer.name === 'reset'
                ? ResetPassword
                : drawer.name === 'config'
                ? ConfigConnect
                : drawer.name === 'finalConfig'
                ? FinalConfigConnect
                : null
            }
          />
        ),
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
```

app.js

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

**Android - The solution:**

animationEnabled: false

Example:

```
<Stack.Screen
            name={drawer.name}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              animationEnabled: false,
            }}
            key={drawer.name}
            component={LoginScreen}
          />
```

You found the problem. In android, the animations make the navigation go very slow and it may seem that it is blocked.

The solution is to add in the animationEnabled option: false

Comment: I didn't can you explain please ?

Comment: You found the problem. In android, the animations make the navigation go very slow and it may seem that it is blocked.

The solution is to add in the animationEnabled option: false

Comment: Write the answer and mark it as complete once you do please